# How to do databinding with two ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I have 2 models, 2 views, and 1 viewmodel.
Basically I want to load the data from a GTSLocation object into a ListItem, but also add two more values from a GTSWorkingSite object that has the same Working Site Guid as the GTSLocation object have.

The item fooA from ObservableCollection＜GTSLocation＞:

```
WorkingSiteId : "A-A-A-A"
Longitude: 60
Latitude: 120
```

The item fooB from ObservableCollection＜GTSLocation＞:

```
WorkingSiteId : null
Longitude: 70
Latitude: 130
```

The item barA from ObservableCollection＜GTSWorkingSite＞:

```
Id: "A-A-A-A"
Name: "WacDonald's"
Description: "A Fastfood resturaunt."
```

The listitem for fooA:

```
WorkingSiteName: "WacDonald's"
WorkingSiteDescription: "A Fastfood resturaunt."
Longitude: 60
Latitude: 120
```

The listitem for fooB:

```
WorkingSiteName: "Unknown Place"
WorkingSiteDescription: "No info to provide"
Longitude: 70
Latitude: 130
```

I can only come up with the solution that is to create another model which contain all the properties I want. Actually is it the only way to go? There must be a more elegant way I guess?

To add up, the reason I have two ObservableCollection is because GTSWorkingSite is also used on the other view (WorkingSiteView.xaml) seperately.

◎Model

```cs
    public class GTSLocation 
    {
        public string WorkingSiteId {get;set;} //GUID
        public double Longitude {get;set;}
        public double Latitude {get;set;}
        public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
    }
    public class GTSWorkingSite
    {
        public string Id {get;set;} //GUID
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Description {get;set;}
    }
```

◎ViewModel

```cs
    public class GeneralViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        //Assume these two collection filled with data
        public ObservableCollection<GTSLocation> UserLocations { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<GTSWorkingSite> WorkingSites { get; set; }
        //Ignored the rest of the code...
    }
```

◎View: UserItemsPage.xaml

```xml
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserLocations}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                       <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                       <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding WorkingSiteName}" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding WorkingSiteDescription}" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Longitude}" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Timestamp}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
               </Grid>
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If this is a bad design from the very begining, I am willing to refactor my code, if anyone could give me suggestion.

Comment: Pardon me that I don't choose the best answer right away. Each of answers is helpful to me. Just give me two days because I would like to see more answers and suggestions being offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty bad because you rely on string (or whatever GUID) mapping between the two classes. If you don't want to create a third model but can refactor current model and if GTSLocation has a 1-1 mapping with GTSWorkingSite anyway then i think you could just do:

1) Refactor the model so that GTSLocation knows about the fact it has a GTSWotkingSite:

```
public class GTSLocation 
{
    public string WorkingSiteId {get;set;} //GUID
    public double Longitude {get;set;}
    public double Latitude {get;set;}
    public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
    //New property -> We will use it in the binding!
    public GTSWorkingSite WorkingSite {get;set;}
}
public class GTSWorkingSite
{
    public string Id {get;set;} //GUID
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

2) Then in your XAML it becomes easy to retrieve the info when populated correctly (note the binding ["."] slight change using the new added `WorkingSite` property):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserLocations}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                       <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                       <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding WorkingSite.Name}" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding WorkingSite.Description}" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Longitude}" />
                   <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Timestamp}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
               </Grid>
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Hope it helps and happy coding!

Comment: I see. :) What bothering me is cpu/memory issue and the repeat of implementation. Maybe the former one is ignorable on modern device nowadays, while the latter is kind of.. ugly? However I didn't realize that the string/GUID mapping strategy is the biggest problem. Thanks for the refactoring tip and the full code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is more complexity in having two BindingContext's on ListView then actually creating the third class and merging those two lists into one.

```
var newList = from locations in UserLocations
              join workingSite in WorkingSites on locations.WorkingSiteId equals workingSite.Id
              select new WhatEverClass(workingSite, locations);
```

In `WhatEverClass` you can have a backing value of `GTSWorkingSite` & `GTSLocation` and whatever fields/properties you want.

What's more, when talking about refactoring you if `WorkingSiteId` is really a `GUID` why didn't you use `GUID` instead of `string`? 

+ you can wrap longitude & latitude into your the class - eg. `GeoCoordinate` or you can create your own class with additional logic (if needed). C# is strongly typed

Comment: Thanks for the LINQ snippet and refactoring suggestion! I didn't know GUID type class. Actually the coordinate one aleady has nested properties, I just flatten them out in order to make the question simpler (without having to attach the Coordinate class), but thanks for the info anyway. :)